# How to read image stored in an oracle SQL BLOB?

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle, blob

I am trying to read image stored as a blob in oracle SQL database. 
Below is the code I tried so far:

```
var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(x.IMAGE1);
console.log(arrayBufferView)
var blob = new Blob([arrayBufferView], {type: "image/jpg"});
var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
var img = new Image();
img.src = imageUrl;
```

However, I am getting broken images. I think it's because of `x.IMAGE1` fields, which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What database library are you using? Is this in a server-side NodeJS script, client-side Electron script, or client-side/browser scripts?

Comment: `allowHalfOpen` is a property on a Socket object. Where are you getting `x` from?

Answer (score 0):

The object you're seeing is a stream, the default type returned for LOBs. You can work with that API as documented here: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-173-streaming-lobs

Alternatively, you can modify your code to fetch the LOB out as a Buffer: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#getting-lobs-as-string-or-buffer-from-plsql

```
const result = await connection.execute(
  `BEGIN lobs_out(:id, :c, :b); END;`,
  { id: 20,
    c: {type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 50000},
    b: {type: oracledb.BUFFER, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 50000}
  }
);

const str = result.outBinds.c;  // a String
const buf = result.outBinds.b;  // a Buffer

. . . // do something with str and buf
```